# Best way to hide previous border?

Tags: css, html, menu, border

I have a menu with several div. Every div has a 1px left border. On hover, I change the background of the current div, but as you can see with the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHkWu/), it's ugly that the previous (grey) border is still visible.

I would like to hide it when I'm on the current selected div. Any ideas?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHkWu/)

```
<div id="main_menu">
    <div class="menu_item"><div class="link">Example</div></div>
    <div class="menu_item"><div class="link">Example</div></div>
    <div class="menu_item"><div class="link">Example</div></div>
    <div class="menu_item"><div class="link">Example</div></div>
</div>
```

To make it more clear, from this:

[image: screen1]

To this:

[image: screen1]

Possibly without using any JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `.menu_item` hover css to this:

```
#main_menu .menu_item:hover {
    background-color:#00437f;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    left:-1px;
}
```

and to maintain text at its position update below css:

```
#main_menu .menu_item:hover .link {
    color:#fff;
    border:0px;
    position:relative;
    left:1px;
}
```

Comment: To add to this, if you gave the styles `position:relative; left:1px;` to `#main_menu .menu_item:hover .link`, the horizontal position of the text would be maintained. [Fiddle update.](http://jsfiddle.net/VHkWu/1/)